# MVC: which CSS class implements Html.EditorFor() method?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

In order to modify the style shown when you use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SomeAttribute)` I want to know how to override the default CSS class without declare a new class for each attribute data type of the model. In other words.

I don't want to do this:

```
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ddlStationId, new {@class="label"})
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ddlStationId, new { ReadMethod = "Read", ReadController = "Receiver",@class="combobox" })
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.txbBrandName,new {@class="textbox"})
```

As you all know, EditorFor() has a different behavior depending on the datatype, so I want to know where is located this class.

I did something by using the UIHint class as a decorator and defined an EditorTemplate, but doesn't allowed me to override the main CSS. Is important to say that I'm using the **Kendo UI** framework. Some extra information which can be relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks tommy! I did something like this, but using UIhint... so, when I declared a property I set some decorators depending on the data type and there I used the Css Class. For example:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Nombre")]
[UIHint("String")]
public string txbName
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

And, on the Editor Template:

```
@model object 

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model, new {@class="k-textbox",style="min-width:200px;" })
```

Finally, the definition of the CSS class "k-textbox"

```
.controls-row .k-textbox {
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I preffer this solution because allows me apply this markup for all textbox in the solution... for my particular case is what I wanted to do:

```
<div class="controls-row">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.txbName) //it shows "Nombre"
     @Html.EditorFor(m => m.txbName) //it declares an editor for string type
</div>
```

Thanks for answering! :)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you override the default templates, there is no "default" class.  Depending on your DataAnnotations, the behavior might be different on the value being shown (formatting strings, perhaps you have a template that puts a datepicker on the text input), but the output of each of the following is consistent across MVC.

```
@Html.LabelFor(x=>x.Property)
```

outputs in HTML

```
<label for="Property">Property Value</label>
```

For a string property

```
@Html.EditorFor(x=>x.SomeStringProperty)
```

outputs in HTML

```
<input type="text" id="SomeStringProperty" name="SomeStringProperty" value=""/>
```

Lastly, a boolean property

```
@Html.EditorFor(x=>x.SomeBoolProperty)
```

outputs in HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="SomeBoolProperty" name="SomeBoolProperty"/>
```

Given this, then in your stylesheet, you need to create classes for top level HTML elements not based on class or id.  Such examples could be

```
<style>
  <!--apply to all labels -->
  label { position: absolute; text-align:right; width:130px; }
  <!--apply to all labels with class check-->
  label.check { font-weight:bold;padding-left:10px }
  <!-- apply to all input and textarea tags-->
  input, textarea { margin-left: 140px; }
  <!-- apply to all input with class special-->
  input.special { font-weight: bold }
</style>
```

If you look in the default stylesheet that comes with an basic MVC template, you will probably see things similar to what I have posted above.  You can edit these with your custom classes.